# Show that $A$ is a zero divisor of $S$ if and only if $A \neq 0$ and $\det(A)=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S=M_2(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $A$ is a zero divisor of $S$ if and only if $A \neq 0$ and $\det(A)=0$.

Backward direction: Suppose  $A \neq 0$ and $\det(A)=0$. Since $A$ is singular, in the equation $AB=0$, $B$ has nontrivial solution, i.e. $B \neq 0$. Hence, $A$ is a zero divisor

Forward direction: Suppose $A$ is a zero divisor of $S$. Then there exists $B \neq 0$ such that $AB=0$. Since $A$ is a zero divisor, $A \neq 0$. Suppose $\det(A) \neq 0$. Then we have $B=0$, contradiction.

Is this proof work?

Comment: You are relying on the relation between $AB=0$ having a nontrivial solution and $\det A$ being nonzero, which is very close to what you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea will work. But your $B$ is a *vector*, not a $2\times 2$ matrix. Easy fix: let $B^\ast$ be the $2\times 2$ whose columns are each equal to your $B$.

**Remark:** Consider the matrix 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A$ is not the zero-matrix. Suppose the determinant $ad-bc$ is equal to $0$. 
We cannot have all of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ equal to $0$. So either at least one of $c$ or $d$ is non-zero, or one of $a$ or $b$ is non-zero. We assume that $c$ and $d$ are not both $0$, and let you take care of the case where they are, but $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$. Let 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} d&d\\-c&-c\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By direct multiplication, you can verify that $AB$ is the zero $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: It wasn't at all clear to me whether OP was taking $B$ to be a matrix or a vector.

Comment: True, it is not clear. But the standard theorem taught at this stage links singularity of matrix to existence of a non-trivial solution of a system of homogeneous equations.

Comment: Regarding the forward direction, can I show by contradiction as indicated as above ?

Comment: I will add a remark that may be helpful. It will take me a while, I tend to have trouble typing matrices.

Comment: For the forward dirction, it all (as usual) depends on what theorems have already been proved about the determinant. Let $U$ and $V$ be the two column vectors of $B$. At least one is not the zero vector, say $U$. since $AB$ is the zero matrix, $AU$ is the zero vector. So $AU$ equal to the zero vector has a non-trivial solution, which (if it has been proved) means the determinant is $0$. If you do not have the theorem yet, then you will need to prove directly that if $A$ kills the non-zero column vector $(x,y)$, then $ad-bc=0$. This is just some algebra.